# How to automatically add dividers between list elements in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to replicate the some of the behavior of `List`. I specifically want to add dividers between all elements. My current code looks like this

```
Customlist {
  Text("...")
  Divider()
  Text("...")
  Divider()
  Text("...")
}
```

I want to remove the dividers and just provide the text nodes, but I have no idea how to inject the dividers automatically in `Customlist`. So the usage I want looks like this:

```
Customlist {
  Text("...")
  Text("...")
  Text("...")
}
```

I assume `Customlist` would have to look something like this (but I don't know how to implement `body`):

```
Customlist<Content: View>: View {
  var content: Content

  init(@ViewBuilder _ b: () -> Content) {
    self.content = b()
  }

  var body: some View {
    // Something using self.content here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Row send rowID(using PreferenceKey) to list.
2. List get all rows's ids, and send the last id to row.
3. row check self'id is equal to last row id.

```swift
/// store all row ids.
fileprivate struct RowsPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: [Namespace.ID] = []
    static func reduce(value: inout [Namespace.ID], nextValue: () -> [Namespace.ID]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    
    fileprivate struct LastRowKey: EnvironmentKey {
        static var defaultValue: Namespace.ID? = nil
    }
    
    /// identity this row id, is last item in list
    var lastRowID: Namespace.ID? {
        get { self[LastRowKey.self] }
        set { self[LastRowKey].self = newValue }
    }
}

struct Row<Content: View>: View {
    
    @Environment(\.lastRowID) var lastRowID
    @Namespace var id
    
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content
            // check self is last row
            if lastRowID != id {
                Divider()
            }
         // send row id to list.
        }.preference(key: RowsPreferenceKey.self, value: [id])
    }
    
}


struct DividerList<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    @State var lastRowID: Namespace.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack { content }
        .onPreferenceChange(RowsPreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
            self.lastRowID = value.last
        })
        /// send row id to Childs
        .environment(\.lastRowID, lastRowID)
    }
    
}

struct DividerList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            DividerList {
                Row {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
                
                Row {
                    Text("World")
                }
                
                Row {
                    Text("!!!")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rMCG.png)

Comment: Amazing answer. Honestly, I've never done nor seen this kind of usage of Environment for passing data from child to parent and back. Also, maybe you could explain a bit more on @Namespace part? Seems like not much on the web about it rn. Anyway, thanks so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI
struct ParentView: View  {
    let array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    var body: some View {
        DividedList{
            VStack{
                //The next init for List would implement something like this
                ForEach(array, id: \.self) { elem in
                    VStack{
                        Text(elem.description)
                        
                        if elem.description != array.last?.description{
                            Divider()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct DividedList<Content: View>: View {
    
    
    var content: Content
    //This is just the first init for the SwiftUI.List if you want the rest you have to implement them individually 
      //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list
      init(@ViewBuilder _ b: () -> Content) {
        self.content = b()
      }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
    }
}

struct DividedList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        //DividedList({Text("test")})
        ParentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: All of the versions adds a divider in the end of the list. I only want dividers in between the elements.

Comment: No they add the `Divider` at the end of the Cell/Line. I added a photo of the result. Maybe if you add a photo of what you want we can compare.

Comment: Ohhh I see the difference. See the new code with a conditional.

Comment: Alright, this is pretty much what I have today. My issue is that I want to use the `DividedList` just like any other SwiftUI component. That is, it should take a `@ViewBuilder` (or maybe there is another way to do this?). My problem is that I can't iterate over the `ViewBuilder` elements.

Comment: What you have already is the first `init` for `SwiftUI.List` If you want all the other options of initializing the `List` you have to implement all the other `init()` and conditionally remove the last divider when creating the Cells/Elements.

Comment: Where do I find these other `init()`?

Comment: in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list you won't find the code behind them but with the `init()` you can make your own implementation. It is the same stuff that pops up as you are typing the class name in XCode, all your options.

Comment: The `ForEach` `init()` start a bit simpler only 3 options and focuses on `DynamicViewContent` that gives you `onDelete`, etc. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach