# SwiftUI - Automatically add dividers between each element of a `ForEach`

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui, swift-keypath

I'm using a `ForEach` to display the contents of an array, then manually showing a divider between each element by checking the element index. Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let animals = ["Apple", "Bear", "Cat", "Dog", "Elephant"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            /// array of tuples containing each element's index and the element itself
            let enumerated = Array(zip(animals.indices, animals))
            ForEach(enumerated, id: \.1) { index, animal in
                Text(animal)

                /// add a divider if the element isn't the last
                if index != enumerated.count - 1 {
                    Divider()
                        .background(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

<kbd>[image: Stack of text with dividers in between]</kbd>

This works, but I'd like a way to automatically add dividers everywhere without writing the `Array(zip(animals.indices, animals))` every time. Here's what I have so far:

```
struct ForEachDividerView<Data, Content>: View where Data: RandomAccessCollection, Data.Element: Hashable, Content: View {
    var data: Data
    var content: (Data.Element) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let enumerated = Array(zip(data.indices, data))
        ForEach(enumerated, id: \.1) { index, data in

            /// generate the view
            content(data)

            /// add a divider if the element isn't the last
            if let index = index as? Int, index != enumerated.count - 1 {
                Divider()
                    .background(.blue)
            }
        }
    }
}

/// usage
ForEachDividerView(data: animals) { animal in
    Text(animal)
}
```

This works great, isolating all the boilerplate `zip` code and still getting the same result. However, this is only because `animals` is an array of `String`s, which conform to [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) — if the elements in my array didn't conform to `Hashable`, it wouldn't work:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let people: [Person] = [
        .init(name: "Anna"),
        .init(name: "Bob"),
        .init(name: "Chris")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            /// Error! Generic struct 'ForEachDividerView' requires that 'Person' conform to 'Hashable'
            ForEachDividerView(data: people) { person in
                Text(person.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's why SwiftUI's `ForEach` comes with an additional initializer, [`init(_:id:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:id:content:)-82hm4), that takes in a custom key path for extracting the ID. I'd like to take advantage of this initializer in my `ForEachDividerView`, but I can't figure it out. Here's what I tried:

```
struct ForEachDividerView<Data, Content, ID>: View where Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable, Content: View {
    var data: Data
    var id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>
    var content: (Data.Element) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let enumerated = Array(zip(data.indices, data))

        /// Error! Invalid component of Swift key path
        ForEach(enumerated, id: \.1.appending(path: id)) { index, data in

            content(data)

            if let index = index as? Int, index != enumerated.count - 1 {
                Divider()
                    .background(.blue)
            }
        }
    }
}


/// at least this part works...
ForEachDividerView(data: people, id: \.name) { person in
    Text(person.name)
}
```

I tried using [`appending(path:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anykeypath/appending(path:)) to combine the first key path (which extracts the element from `enumerated`) with the second key path (which gets the `Hashable` property from the element), but I got `Invalid component of Swift key path`.

How can I automatically add a divider in between the elements of a `ForEach`, even when the element doesn't conform to `Hashable`?

Comment: Apologies for the long question. Btw I have checked [How to automatically add dividers between list elements in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64552511/14351818), but that question is about extending the manual approach and doesn't use `ForEach`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [the article mentioned in a comment](https://movingparts.io/variadic-views-in-swiftui) I built the following. It takes the set of views and places a divider between them.

This is also useful when the views are not being generated by a `ForEach`, especially when one or more of the views is removed conditionally (e.g. using an `if` statement).

```swift
struct Divided<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(DividedLayout()) {
            content
        }
    }

    struct DividedLayout: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
        @ViewBuilder
        func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
            let last = children.last?.id

            ForEach(children) { child in
                child

                if child.id != last {
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Divided_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            Divided {
                Text("Alpha")
                Text("Beta")
                Text("Gamma")
            }
        }
        .previewDisplayName("Vertical")

        HStack {
            Divided {
                Text("Alpha")
                Text("Beta")
                Text("Gamma")
            }
        }
        .previewDisplayName("Horizontal")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this allowed in the App Store?

Comment: I have used this in apps that were approved for sale in the App Store.

Answer (score 8):

Simple way

```
struct ContentView: View {
let animals = ["Apple", "Bear", "Cat", "Dog", "Elephant"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {

        ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { animal in
            Text(animal)

            if animals.last != animal  {
                Divider()
                    .background(.blue)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Typically the type inside animals must be Identifiable. In which case the code will be modified as.

```
          if animals.last.id != animal.id {...}
```

This will avoid any equatable requirements/ implementations

Comment: This is the simplest one ☝️ Other answers seem to be quite overengineered

Answer (score 1):

Does everything need to be in a ForEach? If not, you can consider not using indices at all:

```swift
struct ForEachDividerView<Data, Content, ID>: View where Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable, Content: View {
    var data: Data
    var id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>
    var content: (Data.Element) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        if let first = data.first {
            content(first)
            
            ForEach(data.dropFirst(), id: id) { element in
                Divider()
                    .background(.blue)
                content(element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

1. [`appending(path:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anykeypath/appending(path:)) seems to only work on key paths erased to [`AnyKeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anykeypath).
2. Then, `appending(path:)` returns an optional `AnyKeyPath?` — this needs to get cast down to `KeyPath<(Data.Index, Data.Element), ID>` to satisfy the `id` parameter.

```
struct ForEachDividerView<Data, Content, ID>: View where Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable, Content: View {
    var data: Data
    var id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>
    var content: (Data.Element) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        let enumerated = Array(zip(data.indices, data))

        /// first create a `AnyKeyPath` that extracts the element from `enumerated`
        let elementKeyPath: AnyKeyPath = \(Data.Index, Data.Element).1

        /// then, append the `id` key path to `elementKeyPath` to extract the `Hashable` property
        if let fullKeyPath = elementKeyPath.appending(path: id) as? KeyPath<(Data.Index, Data.Element), ID> {
            ForEach(enumerated, id: fullKeyPath) { index, data in

                content(data)

                if let index = index as? Int, index != enumerated.count - 1 {
                    Divider()
                        .background(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let people: [Person] = [
        .init(name: "Anna"),
        .init(name: "Bob"),
        .init(name: "Chris")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEachDividerView(data: people, id: \.name) { person in
                Text(person.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

<kbd>[image: Person names stacked vertically, with blue divider in between]</kbd>

Comment: It is really too complicated for such a simple task. Upvoted @arthas because I always used that one. Moreover on some of WWDC22 session I met same and they even included handling that automatically.

Comment: @Asperi do you have a link to that session? I'd like to take a look. Thanks

Comment: Btw this article looks interesting: https://movingparts.io/variadic-views-in-swiftui

Comment: Searched... sorry, that was about different, my mistake... anyway still on my mind... and accepted answer - doubtful, no common .onMove/.onDelete/... separated container, etc... applicable IMO as corner case. Not for me, but, ok to know.